# How to deal with a second event-loop with message-dispatch?

Tags: windows, event-handling, directshow

I am working on a program which is essentially single-threaded, and its only thread is the main event-loop thread. Consequently, all its data structures are basically not protected by anything like critical region.

Things work fine until it recently integrates some new functions based on DirectShow API. Some DirectShow APIs open a second event-loop and within that second loop it dispatch messages (i.e. invoke other event-handling callbacks unpredictably). So when a second event-handling function is invoked, it might damage the data struct which is being accessed by the function that invokes the DirectShow API.

I have some experience in kernel programming. And what comes in my mind is that, for a single-threaded program, how it should deal with its data structure is very like how kernel should deal with per-CPU data structure. And in kernel, when a function accesses per-CPU data, it must disable the interrupt (very like the message-dispatching in a second event-loop). However, I find there is no easy way to either avoid invoke DirectShow API or to prevent the create of a second event-loop within them, is there any way?

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what you are asking. Do you want to prevent DirectShow from firing events, do you want to prevent DirectShow from pumping messages, or do you want to ensure synchronous access to your data? If you simply want to ignore DirectShow's events, try checking the Sender parameter before doing anything in your handler.

Comment: His problem is re-entrancy.  His main message loop receives a message and calls some event handler to handle it.  The handler begins updating a data structure and before it finishes calls an API function.  Internally, the API function enters a modal loop.  It then dispatches a message, re-entering his WindProc.  His code then calls a handler for the message, which updates the same data structure, corrupting it.

Comment: Explicit modal loops aren't the only problem. Even something as innocuous as UpdateWindow can cause a WM_MOUSEACTIVATE message to get processed.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=490461#c11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible solutions that come to mind, depending on exactly what's going wrong and your code:

1. Make sure your data structures are in a consistent state before calling any APIs that run a modal loop.
2. If that's not possible, you can use a simple boolean variable to protect the structure.  If it's set, then simply abort any attempt to update it or queue the update for later.  Another option is to abort the previous operation.
3. If the problem is user generated events, then disable the problematic menus or buttons while the operation is in progress.  Alternatively, you could display a modal dialog.

Answer (score 1):

mutexes.  semaphores.  locking.  whatever name you want to call it, that's what you need.

Comment: Mutex, semaphores, locking are for multi-threading. My situation is not a multi-threading but rather re-entry problem.